# Differences in Classloading

Tags: java, classloader

**Enviroment**

I have two different Classloaders one custom and the other one seems to be `sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader`. Everything should be loaded throught the custom classloader.

**Problem**

A given Class is loaded once twice (one time for each classloader) and internally somehow casted which leads to a classcast exception (it may be necessary to know here that the custom classloader does some JDO enhancing).
Further investigations showed up, that `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassloader()` returns the right classloader and `getClass().getClassloader()` returns the wrong `AppClassLoader`.
I guess the most important point is at the point the AppClassLoader is used the class is referenced directly within the code with `Class<A> c = A.class;`.

**Questions**

1. Is there a different mechanism for loading a class directly referenced within the code (like mentioned above)?
2. What do I have to do to use the same classloader everywhere in my application?
3. Do you have any references on this topic? I was already looking around but I guess I am missing some important buzzwords to look for.

Thanks in advance!
Any help (even just words to look up for) are appreciated!

Comment: When I was studying Custom Class loaders.. I found [this blog post](http://www.journaldev.com/349/java-classloader) really very helpful. I think it covers what you're trying to do.